# Check points inside a given radious using only an array

Tags: javascript, gps, leaflet, markers

I'm creating an app that's using leaftlet to register GPS location of a specific place or multiple places and saves them on a Table [lat,lng] , this happens only on the backoffice.
On the frontend I will get the current position and I would like to create a "n" Km radious based on that position and after that filter all records in given radious.

Now the issue, I will not display any map on the frontend, the goal is only to list the records inside that radious, leaflet is not displayed due to traffic.

Any Idea how can this be done?

Comment: a^2 + b^2 = c^2

Comment: @TKoL your formula is for Euclidean geometry. If OP uses GPS coordinates, they likely use spherical geometry.

Comment: @ghybs fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not display a map, you probably do not Leaflet.

While Leaflet provides you with methods to compute distances, there are many other geospatial libraries that offer similar feature, without the need to display anything. E.g. you might be interested in Turfjs's [distance](https://turfjs.org/docs/#distance):

```js
var from = turf.point([-75.343, 39.984]);
var to = turf.point([-75.534, 39.123]);
var options = {units: 'miles'};

var distance = turf.distance(from, to, options);
```

That being said, if you have a lot of data points in your database, you might investigate the possibility of implementing the filtering directly in backend database, by using spatial query, if your [database supports it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database).